# how to draw rectangle Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have coordinates, centroid, bounding box. I want to draw a colorful rectangle, but not jsut a frame like this:

```
rectangle('Position', stats(i).BoundingBox, ...
          'Linewidth', 3, 'EdgeColor', 'r', 'LineStyle', '--');
```

I want this rectangle to be red, blue..

Any ideas?

Comment: Did my answer helped you? Please consider accepting it then (green check mark on the left). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about this function?

```
function h = plotRectangle(PosVector, color)

X = PosVector;

x = [X(1) X(1)+X(3) X(1)+X(3)  X(1)        X(1)];
y = [X(2) X(2)      X(2)+X(4)  X(2)+X(4)   X(2)];

h = fill(x,y,color);

end
```

Comment: I also want to draw this rectangle on my image.How can I do that?